# SQL statement to display both the entries that have not been included and as well as included

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create a stored procedure when a user initially creates a new form and included some of the entities he wants and then later comes back and edits the entities and adds more to them.

So I would like to display all the entities which  he has selected and not selected in table.

Here is the stored procedure I tried but it only returns the entities that have not been included.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateEntitiesInRCM]   
    @RCM_ID INT,
    @EntityID INT,
    @Comments VARCHAR(1000),
    @included BIT
AS  
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [tblEntitiesInRCM] (RCM_ID, EntityID, Comments, Included)   
    VALUES (@RCM_ID, @EntityID, @Comments, @included)

    IF (@included = 0)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM tblRCM_AllCtrl 
        WHERE RCM_ID = @RCM_ID 
          AND controlID IN (SELECT ControlID 
                            FROM [tblControl_Library] 
                            WHERE EntityID = @EntityID)
    END
END
```

Comment: Are you using mySQL or SQL Server? You tagged both.

Comment: @HardCode I am using SQL Server